# How to get max of dates list with stream, when having nulls in list

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I have following code:

```
List<LocalDate> dates = Arrays.asList(null, null, 
    LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().minusDays(9));

LocalDate max = dates.stream()
    .max(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())).get();
```

Which produce null pointer exception when I try to get the max, but when trying to get min it works ok. It seems unclear cause `max` takes `Comparator` which handles null values. How to sort such array with stream preserving null values.

By the way, I checked JavaDoc of `max`, which states:

> @throws NullPointerException if the maximum element is null

EDIT:

```
LocalDate max = dates.stream()
    .max(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())).orElse(null);
```

Throws null pointer as well.

Comment: just add a filter clause to remove nulls from stream before doing any other computation.

Comment: [Why is Optional.get() without calling isPresent() bad](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/318912/why-is-optional-get-without-calling-ispresent-bad-but-not-iterator-next)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you expect the answer to be `null` because it contains one you can do your own reduction.

```
List<LocalDate> dates = Arrays.asList(null, null,
        LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().minusDays(9));

LocalDate max = dates.stream()
        .reduce(LocalDate.MIN,
                BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
System.out.println(max);
```

prints

```
null
```

NOTE: This is different in the sense that an empty list returns LocalDate.MIN.

A less obvious option is to replace `null` with `LocalDate.MAX` assuming this is never used.

```
LocalDate max = dates.stream()
        .map(d -> d == null ? LocalDate.MAX : d)
        .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
        .map(d -> LocalDate.MAX.equals(d) ? null : d)
        .orElse(null);
```

This returns `null` for an empty list.

Comment: very nice! was not aware of `LocalDate.MIN`, I wish I knew about it before - could have won a couple or arguments :)

Comment: @Eugene although MIN is a large negative date, anything before about the 1750s is likely to be fraught. e.g. there was no 0 in the Roman number and no year 0 in the Julian calendar.

Comment: I understand that- I looked at the implementation already, thank you anyway. It's good that I don't deal with such dates (like 99% of people), but when you need to reduce with an identity then definitely something like this needed

Answer (score 3):

Having `null` values in the `List` and looking for the max value? Firstly get rid of the `null` values using `Stream::filter`. Then the job is easy:

```
LocalDate max = dates.stream()
                     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                     .max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
```

If you insist on using the `Comparator` only, use [`Comparator::nullsFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) instead:

```
LocalDate max = dates.stream().max(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())).get();
```

- [`Comparator::nullsFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) returns a null-friendly comparator that considers null to be less than non-null.
- [`Comparator::nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-) returns a null-friendly comparator that considers null to be greater than non-null.

Comment: Maybe having nulls in list and looking for max is not the best idea, but provided comparator defines how to treat null values.

Comment: I realized after writing my initial answer that max will still fill with `nullsFirst` when the list contains only nulls. `max` does not allow null as a value.